# R Printing ftable() output to csv with factor names

Tags: r

I'm working with `ftable` in R to create contingency tables.

I want to print an ftable object to a csv, but when I use `write.csv()` on the ftable object the csv no longer lists the factor names that are included in the ftable on R. This is the type of output that I get

Here's an example ftable in R

```
   structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(12L, 7L), class = "ftable", row.vars = list(
    ï..petal_size = c("large ", "small", "small "), stem_length = c("long", 
    "long ", "short", "short ")), col.vars = list(flow_color = c("blue", 
"green", "indigo ", "orange", "red  ", "violet", "yellow")))
```

[image]

Is there a solution to this such that I can keep the factor names?

Comment: First use `as.character`? Just a guess since you have provided not data, not to mention not providing code.

Comment: Updated with ftable from dput()

Comment: That's a dataframe, not an ftable. Do you just want to write that to disk?

Comment: Hmm strange. This is the output I get from doing dput() on an ftable object. Let me see if I can figure something out

Comment: We still don't see any code, so your claim that this is an `ftable`-object seems flimsy at present.

Comment: @42 updated. Made mistake on putting in df instead of ftable

Comment: As Miha snote, `write.ftable` has no sep parameter so there are no commas or other separators. It's being output as a fixed field format. Both LibreOffice and Excel can handle fixed field formats with a bit of hand placement of separators. `format.ftable gives you a character matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use the function `write.ftable` but you will have a lot of manual work to do, due to the fact everything (in CSV file) will be written in a single column

```
write.ftable(ftable(df), file = "table.csv", quote = FALSE)
# And the otuput NOTE: WHEN OPENING CSV EVERYTHING WILL BE IN SINGLE COLUMN
                          flow_color blue green indigo  orange red   violet yellow
i..petal_size stem_length                                                         
large         long                      1     0       1      1     2      1      1
              long                      0     0       0      0     0      0      0
              short                     0     0       0      0     0      1      1
              short                     0     1       0      1     0      0      0
small         long                      1     2       0      0     1      0      0
              long                      0     0       1      0     0      0      0
              short                     0     0       1      0     0      1      0
              short                     1     0       0      0     0      0      1
small         long                      0     0       0      0     0      0      0
              long                      0     0       0      0     0      0      0
              short                     0     0       0      1     0      0      0
              short                     0     0       0      0     0      0  

0
```

Or another option using `stats` to first format `ftable` and then use `write.table`

```
df <- ftable(df)
cont <- stats:::format.ftable(df, quote = FALSE)
write.table(cont, sep = ";", file = "table.csv")
```

And the output
[image]

Comment: the sep should be ',' ?