# Exploring Combined Factors in R

Tags: r

This is a follow up to this post here 
[R Printing ftable() output to csv with factor names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953470/r-printing-ftable-output-to-csv-with-factor-names?noredirect=1#comment96673766_54953470)
Will include background here as well.

I have some census data where people were allowed to list their race as either one or a combination of many different races. We allow them to select from these choices.

American Indian

East Asian

Pacific Islander

Black or African American

White or Caucasian

Hispanic or Latino/a

South Asian

Middle Eastern

Other

The resulting data is quite messy if you want to make contingency tables of the race of people because the data output, which I've provided a sample of below, can have one person listed as many different races.

```
structure(list(Race = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 
5L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Black or African American", 
"Black or African American,White or Caucasian", "East Asian", 
"East Asian,Pacific Islander", "Hispanic or Latino/a", "Other", 
"Pacific Islander", "South Asian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian,Hispanic or Latino/a", 
"White or Caucasian,Middle Eastern"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

To reduce the number of factors I turned all the people with multiple races in a cell (using the method described in the previous post) to "Mixed". Like a cell in the above dataframe that says "White or Caucasian,Middle Eastern" became "Mixed". However, I'd like to further explore the demographics of the people I changed to "Mixed". What I'd like to do is create a dataframe with person as a row and each of the different races as a column. Then if the person listed themselves as any of the races that column for race will be a 1. If they did not list themselves as that race it will be a 0. For example if someone listed themselves as both "White" and "East Asian" their row in the dataframe will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to split the single column into multiple columns (and I would strongly recommend avoiding factors:

```
dfdat <- read.table(text=as.character(dat[[1]][-1]), sep=",", 
                     fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The run apply over the values by row (and of course transposing to restore the origianl dimensions:

```
dftbl <- t( apply(dfdat, 1, function(x){ 0+   # adding zero to logical coerces to numeric
      c( 'American Indian',     
     'East Asian',     
     'Pacific Islander',   
     'Black or African American',     
     'White or Caucasian',     
     'Hispanic or Latino/a',     
     'South Asian',     
     'Middle Eastern',     
     'Other') %in% x}))
 dftbl
 #===================
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

Then just convert to data.frame, add back the vector of column names and cbind to the application of apply using the `any` function.

Answer (score 3):

Could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number(), dummy = 1) %>%
  separate_rows(Race, sep = ",") %>%
  spread(Race, dummy, fill = 0)
```

Note that as there is no `ID` I've created one that is equal to row number.

Output:

```
   ID Black or African American East Asian Hispanic or Latino/a Middle Eastern Other Pacific Islander
1   1                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
2   2                         1          0                    0              0     0                0
3   3                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
4   4                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
5   5                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
6   6                         0          0                    0              1     0                0
7   7                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
8   8                         0          0                    0              1     0                0
9   9                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
10 10                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
11 11                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
12 12                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
13 13                         0          0                    0              0     0                1
14 14                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
15 15                         0          0                    0              1     0                0
16 16                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
17 17                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
18 18                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
19 19                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
20 20                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
21 21                         1          0                    0              0     0                0
22 22                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
23 23                         1          0                    0              0     0                0
24 24                         0          0                    0              0     1                0
25 25                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
26 26                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
27 27                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
28 28                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
29 29                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
30 30                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
31 31                         0          0                    1              0     0                0
32 32                         1          0                    0              0     0                0
33 33                         1          0                    0              0     0                0
34 34                         0          0                    0              0     0                0
35 35                         0          1                    0              0     0                1
36 36                         0          1                    0              0     0                0
   South Asian White or Caucasian
1            0                  0
2            0                  1
3            0                  0
4            0                  1
5            0                  1
6            0                  1
7            0                  0
8            0                  1
9            0                  0
10           0                  0
11           0                  0
12           0                  0
13           0                  0
14           0                  0
15           0                  1
16           0                  0
17           0                  1
18           0                  1
19           0                  1
20           0                  1
21           0                  1
22           0                  0
23           0                  1
24           0                  0
25           0                  1
26           0                  1
27           0                  0
28           0                  1
29           1                  0
30           0                  0
31           0                  0
32           0                  0
33           0                  1
34           0                  1
35           0                  0
36           0                  0
```